# Can't insert multiple values into DB2 by using UNION ALL and generate IDs from sequence

Tags: sql, db2, union-all

I've created sequence by following statement:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MAIN.MY_SEQUENCE START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 50;
```

And table by following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE MAIN.EMPLOYEES(
        ID INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        NAME VARCHAR(512), 
        EMAIL VARCHAR(254),

        PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

Now when I try to insert a new record by using following statement:

```
INSERT INTO MAIN EMPLOYEES (ID, NAME, EMAIL) 
VALUES (MAIN.MY_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL, 'Name 1', 'email1@example.com') UNION ALL
VALUES (MAIN.MY_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL, 'Name 2', 'email2@example.com')
```

I get an error:

```
"NEXTVAL FOR MAIN.MY_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL" cannot be specified in this context.. SQLCODE=-348, SQLSTATE=428F9, DRIVER=4.17.30
```

When I try to insert a single row everything works fine.

I have found a list of restrictions on using `NEXT VALUE` [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.codes/src/tpc/n348.html) but here not mentioned my case or I couldn't find it.

My question is it possible to insert multiple rows by using ID from sequence, and if yes, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does list your case.  The documentation contains this:

> The NEXT VALUE expressions cannot be specified in the following contexts:
>   ...
>   •SELECT statement for which the outer SELECT is combined with another SELECT statement using a set operator **such as** UNION, EXCEPT, or INTERSECT
>   ....

(emphasis mine) This statement isn't exhaustive, and because `UNION ALL` is considered a set operation, the operation is excluded.

This should be fixable - I'm a little surprised you wrote the statement the way you did; DB2 allows you to comma-separate data rows.  That is, the following should be valid:

```
INSERT INTO MAIN.EMPLOYEES (ID, NAME, EMAIL) 
VALUES (MAIN.MY_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL, 'Name 1', 'email1@example.com'),  
       (MAIN.MY_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL, 'Name 2', 'email2@example.com')
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution correct but `VALUES` should be specified only once, otherwise I get an error `No authorized routine named "VALUES" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=4.17.30` Regarding your citation `SELECT statement for which the outer SELECT is combined with another SELECT...` why my `INSERT` statement considered to be `SELECT` I didn't understand this moment.

Comment: ....I meant to write that, yes.  I believe the statement is considered an implicit `SELECT` statement, yes, because it's a shortcut.  The important part is the set operation.