# Ebean Annotations - Using sequences to generate IDs in DB2

Tags: db2, ebean

I'm trying to use sequences to generate incremented IDs for my tables in DB2. It works when I send SQL statements directly to the database, but when using ebean the statement fails. Here's the field in Java:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "TABLENAME_IDNAME_TRIG")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "TABLENAME_IDNAME_TRIG", sequenceName = "TABLENAME_IDNAME_SEQ")
@Column(name = "IDNAME")
private Long id;
```

Here's the column in SQL (From TOAD):

```
Name            Data type   Not Null    Default Generated   Bit Data    Scope   Identity    
IDNAME          INTEGER     Yes                             No                  No
```

And here's the sequence definition in SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE SCHEMA.TABLENAME_IDNAME_SEQ 
  AS INTEGER CACHE 50 ORDER;
```

And the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SCHEMA.TABLENAME_IDNAME_TRIG
  NO CASCADE BEFORE INSERT
  ON TABLENAME
  REFERENCING 
    NEW AS OBJ
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  SET obj.IDNAME=NEXT VALUE FOR SCHEMA.TABLENAME_IDNAME_SEQ;
END;
```

What is the issue with my annotations here? As a(n important) side note - when I set GenerationType to AUTO, TABLE, or IDENTITY, it works, even though it shouldn't, because I'm also using this object to represent a parallel oracle table which also uses sequences for ID generation.

Edited to include error message:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Error getting sequence nextval
...
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-348, SQLSTATE=428F9, SQLERRMC=NEXTVAL FOR SCHEMA.TABLENAME_IDNAME_SEQ, DRIVER=4.19.49
```

EDIT 2: The specific Sql statement that is failing is:

```
values nextval for QA_CONNECTION_ICONNECTIONI_SEQ union values nextval for QA_CONNECTION_ICONNECTIONI_SEQ union values nextval for QA_CONNECTION_ICONNECTIONI_SEQ
```

Which is SQL generated by Ebean. This is a smaller version of the real statement, which is repeated 20 times, so I'm guessing something screws up when generating the caching query.

EDIT 3: I believe this might be a bug in Ebean's use of DB2 sequences. This function generates SQl that returns an error for me when used with db2

```
public DB2SequenceIdGenerator(BackgroundExecutor be, DataSource ds, String seqName, int batchSize) {
  super(be, ds, seqName, batchSize);
  this.baseSql = "values nextval for " + seqName;
  this.unionBaseSql = " union " + baseSql;
}
```

EDIT 4: Based on this SO link I think it is a bug.
[Can't insert multiple values into DB2 by using UNION ALL and generate IDs from sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34381352/cant-insert-multiple-values-into-db2-by-using-union-all-and-generate-ids-from-s)
The correct class probably looks like this? Though I haven't ever tried building the library, so I couldn't test it. Time to learn how to open a defect I guess.

```
public class DB2SequenceIdGenerator extends SequenceIdGenerator {

  private final String baseSql;
  private final String unionBaseSql;
  private final String startSql;

  public DB2SequenceIdGenerator(BackgroundExecutor be, DataSource ds, String seqName, int batchSize) {
    super(be, ds, seqName, batchSize);
    this.startSql = "values "
    this.baseSql = "(nextval for " + seqName);
    this.unionBaseSql = ", " + baseSql;
  }

  public String getSql(int batchSize) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(startSql);
    sb.append(baseSql);
    for (int i = 1; i < batchSize; i++) {
      sb.append(unionBaseSql);
    }

    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your setup is telling JPA to get the ID value from a sequence and use it within the insert.  I'm guessing this is interfering with your trigger, which is also setting the ID value.  Turn on logging for your JPA provider and see the statements that are being executed to determine what is wrong, but I think you should probably not use the trigger in the database.  Identity may be working as it tells the JPA provider to lookup the sequence value that was set after the insert statement executes, which matches what your trigger is doing.

Comment: `but when using ebean the statement fails` ... you don't say what the error is though? Certainly Ebean is not expecting the trigger to be there though. Note that DB2 supports both Identity and Sequences ... so the presumption is that you have thought about that.

Comment: Isn't Ebean an implementation of JPA - it uses JPA annotations. I'll remove mention of it if it isn't. I've included the stack trace now, but the other logging didnt return anything of note.

I was hoping to use the same class for OracleDB and DB2, which Is why I'm trying to implement sequence generated IDs in DB2

Comment: Ok, cleaned it up. Deleting the trigger but leaving the sequence and annotations doesn't resolve the issue, returning the same error.

Comment: Is there a list of ebean properties I can set in the properties file? I can't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary workaround for those interested: in ebean.properties, set

```
ebean.databaseSequenceBatchSize=1
```